# Some of my Python scripts are not working on PHP

Tags: php, python, linux

I'm setting up a Apache 2, PHP 7, Python 3.6.3 on my Raspberry pi (Ubuntu)
I want execute Python script using PHP.

I've tried execute below code, but it does not work.

This is my body tag.

**con_LED.php:**

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <button name="LightON" value="on">LightON</button> 
    </form>

    <form method="post">
    <button name="LightOFF" value="off">LightOFF</button> 

    </form>
    <p></p>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["LightON"])) {
    exec("python3 /var/www/html/LEDON.py", $output, $var);
    print_r($output."<br>");
    print_r($var);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["LightOFF"])) {
    exec("python3 /var/www/html/LEDOFF.py");
    print_r($output);
    print_r($var);
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

I did some some troubleshooting.
To check, I replace my code to:

```
exec("ls -al", $output, $var)
```

Which works.

I also made:

**a.py:**

```
with open("t1.txt","a") as f:
    f.write("Heelo\n")
```

And executed:

```
exec("python3 /var/www/html/a.py", $output, $var);
```

This also works (meaning I can see `t1.txt` file on my server).

My project is using con_LED.php code to turn the LED on and off.
But my code isn't working.

Of course, I also tried this code directly on shell, which is working.
Does anyone know what my problem is?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Apache user can't access user files, if you create an wwdata user app, all files need be under `/var/www`, and `Python3` not an  user on your computer(tell him to `BASH`) !

Comment: it is supposed to turn LED if press turn on button.. But it isnt work